# Sequence and series of function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

For $(x,y)\in R^2$, consider the series $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{l,k=0}^n \frac{k^2x^ky^l}{l!}$. Then the series converges for $(x,y)$ in
$ \\ 1.(-1,1)\times(0,\infty)\\ 2. R\times(-1,1) \\ 3. (-1,1)\times(-1,1) \\ 4. R\times R $

I considered the series separately. The series $\sum_{k=0}^n {k^2x^k}$ converges for $x<1$ and the series $\sum_{l=0}^n \frac{y^l}{l!}$ converges in (0,$\infty$) and in $[-1,1]$. I don't how to solve further, can we apply Able's test here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $n \to \infty$,
the series
$\sum_{k=0}^n {k^2x^k}
$
converges for
$|x| < 1$
and
$\sum_{l=0}^n \frac{y^l}{l!}
$
converges for all finite $y$
so I would say that
the result is
$(-1, 1) \times R 
$.

Comment: I didn't know that directly we can check the convergence of product of two convergent series. thank you